# Open random URL from a range

Tags: vba, random, openurl

I would need to open a random selected link from a cell to a website in my list. My internet links are put in column B, but I cannot get it to open the hyperlink after it has selected a cell from my list.

```
Sub Test()  
Dim Sh As Worksheet  
Dim Rng As Range 
Dim Cell As Range 

Set Sh = Worksheets("Sheet1") 

With Sh 
    Set Rng = .Range("C1:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row) 
End With 

For Each Cell In Rng
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Cell.Value 
Next Cell  

End Sub
```

Comment: Wlcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi! 
Sorry, I did not notice someone answered! I'm fairly new at vba and I just tried to open a link from my list written in column B. It won't just choose at random which hyperlink it opens, it opens them all. This is what I had:
Sub Test()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Set Sh = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With Sh
        Set Rng = .Range("C1:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    For Each Cell In Rng
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Cell.Value
    Next Cell
End Sub

Please help me out of my misery :)

Comment: Edit your question to include your code. Good luck

Comment: Code added, finally!

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure I got it right:

- The addresses are stored in column B (in your code you're using column C)
- You don't want to open all of the addresses, but only one random one?
- The addresses are full URLs? (Like "https://stackoverflow.com/")

I tidied up your code a little bit. Read the comments, to understand what is happening.

```
Sub Test()
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Cell As Range

Set Sh = Worksheets(1)

' Get a Range object of all possible addresses
Set Rng = Intersect(Sh.UsedRange, Sh.Range("B:B"))

' Open one random element of them
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Rng(Int(Rnd * Rng.Count) + 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, it opens the same hyperlink every time I open the file. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: I forgot, in VBA, the Rnd function needs to be initialized. Just write `Randomize` at the beginning of the code